# Redirect and fetch data from first page input values | WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

WordPress Redirect and post with javscript, first i click on submit button i need to save data to wordpress insert post. and after redirect to another page, so i need some input values get inside redirected page.

when user click submit save data wp_post insert option(I did it) and then redirect another page( redirection working now ) i cannot access data from first page to 2nd page.

- this is my form:

  ```
  <form id=""  class="zon-form" action="#" method="post" data-url="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>">
  <input type="text" class="field-input" placeholder="Adult" id="name" name="name" required>
  ```
- this my javascript:

  ```
              if (r.name)
                  if (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(String(r.email).toLowerCase()))
                      if (r.message) {
                          var t = a.dataset.url,
                              s = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(a));
                          a.querySelector(".js-form-submission").classList.add("show"), fetch(t, {
                              method: "POST",
                              body: s

                          }).then(function(e) {

                              window.location = '/wordpress/payment';




                              //   return e.json()


                          }).catch(function(e) {
                              o(), a.querySelector(".js-form-error").classList.add("show")
                          }).then(function(e) {
                              o(), 0 !== e && "error" !== e.status ? (a.querySelector(".js-form-success").classList.add("show"), a.reset()) : a.querySelector(".js-form-error").classList.add("show")
                          })
                      } else a.querySelector('[data-error="invalidMessage"]').classList.add("show");
              else a.querySelector('[data-error="invalidEmail"]').classList.add("show");
              else a.querySelector('[data-error="invalidName"]').classList.add("show")
          })
      })
  }, {}]
  ```

Any help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write your data to `_SESSION` or pass them via GET to your redirect Url. `wp_insert_post` returns the ID of the new post, so you could only pass this and then read the post on your redirected page.

Comment: i need more details.

Comment: About what exactly?

Comment: i need any modification in JavaScript.

Comment: `save data wp_post insert option(I did it)` > that's when you could save your data in a `_SESSION` aswell. You know about [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), do you?

Comment: i can use with _session custom metabox.